# Trigger Javascript, Java, or a Bash Script on submit in Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon

I would like to know if it is possible to trigger either a Java servlet, Javascript or a local Bash script when I submit a form in orbeon?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Calling Javascript**:

You can call Javascript by adding the following inside your action:

```
 <xxf:script>
//Add your script here
</xxf:script>
```

**Calling a Java Servlet:**

Create a submission: If you are using the Form Builder you can do it by creating a HTTP service, similar to the way a service is created in this link: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/fb-fr/call-service

If you are not using the Form Builder or prefer to write the submission manually:

```
<x:submission id="my-submission"
  method=""
  validate=""
  relevant=""
  resource="" replace="none" ../>
```

After creating a submission to call your Servlet, you have to send it from your action and it'll call the Servlet: `<xf:send submission="my-submission"/>`

http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-advanced-submissions

**Action and Events**

If you want to call it after submiting and saving the form and you are using Form Builder:

```
<xf:action ev:event="fr-data-save-done" ev:observer:"fr-form-model">
//Call the javascript or Servlet
</xf:action>
```

If you are not using Form Builder, just change ev:event/ev:observer according to your needs. xf:send also accepts these attributes.